# Finding the Common Ratio by the first term and the sum to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

I need to clarify if the way of working out is correct for finding the common ratio, given the first term of a geometric series and its sum to infinity.

First term: a = 8

Given Sum: S = 400

Ratio: r = ?

**My procedure is:**

**S** = 400 = 8 $\frac{1-r∞}{ 1 - r}$

**S** = 400 = $\frac{8}{1 - r}$

400 $\cdot$ $(1 - r)$ = 8

(1 - r) = $\frac{8}{400}$

-r = $\frac{8}{400}$ - 1

r = -1 ($\frac{8}{400}$ -1)

r = 0.98

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, but please don't write things like $r^\infty$, this is not well defined. You are encouraged to start your solution like this:

Given a geometric sequence $a_{n+1}=r\cdot a_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ with $a_0=8$, $|r|<1$ and the sum $$ S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \frac{a_0}{1-r}$$ given by $S=400$, we can calculate $r$ as such: $400=\frac{8}{1-r}$ [your steps following]